# Basis and dimensions for quadratic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

> How do I find the basis and dimension for the set of all quadratic polynomials p(x)=ax^2+bx+c that satisfy p(1)=0.

Comment: I suppose the question should say "a" basis, not "the" basis. There is certainly more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : $p(1) = 0$ iff $(x-1)$ divides $p(x)$. Since $p$ has degree 2, it can be written as
$$
p(x) = (x-1)(\alpha x+ \beta) = \alpha x(x-1) +\beta(x-1)
$$
for some real numbers $\alpha, \beta$.

Do you see a basis and the dimension from this?